# PostgreSQL: how to convert from Unix epoch to date?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, type-conversion, epoch

The statement gives me the date and time.

How could I modify the statement so that it returns only the date (and not the time)?

```
SELECT to_timestamp( TRUNC( CAST( epoch_ms AS bigint ) / 1000 ) );
```

Answer (score 222, accepted):

You use `to_timestamp` function and then cast the timestamp to `date`

```
 select to_timestamp(epoch_column)::date;
```

You can use more standard `cast` instead of `::`

```
select cast(to_timestamp(epoch_column) as date);
```

More details:

```
/* Current time */
 select now();  -- returns timestamp

/* Epoch from current time;
   Epoch is number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00+00 */
 select extract(epoch from now()); 

/* Get back time from epoch */
 -- Option 1 - use to_timestamp function
 select to_timestamp( extract(epoch from now()));
 -- Option 2 - add seconds to 'epoch'
 select timestamp with time zone 'epoch' 
         + extract(epoch from now()) * interval '1 second';

/* Cast timestamp to date */
 -- Based on Option 1
 select to_timestamp(extract(epoch from now()))::date;
 -- Based on Option 2
 select (timestamp with time zone 'epoch' 
          + extract(epoch from now()) * interval '1 second')::date;
```

In your case:

```
 select to_timestamp(epoch_ms / 1000)::date;
```

[PostgreSQL Docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: doesn't seem to work, i get syntax error. Did it change as of 2018?

Comment: well i ran the `select to_timestamp(extract(epoch epoch_ms))::date;` verbatim and it gave a `syntax error near epoch_ms`. I went to find other solutions and eventually this worked for me `SELECT TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + (start_dt) * INTERVAL '1 second' as started_on`. Could you please explain the difference between `TIMESTAMP` and `to_timestamp()`?

Comment: TIMESTAMP is just column type where to_timestamp is a build in function that translates unix epoch to timestamp starting calculations from '1970-01-01 00:00:00+00'

Comment: @cryanbhu, your error was caused by not typing `from` between `epoch` and `epoch_ms`; i.e., you should have typed `epoch from epoch_ms` inside the `extract` function.

Answer (score 31):

```
select to_timestamp(cast(epoch_ms/1000 as bigint))::date
```

worked for me

Comment: any idea how to make this work for older version (Postgres 8.0 / Redshift)?

Answer (score 10):

On Postgres 10:

`SELECT to_timestamp(CAST(epoch_ms as bigint)/1000)`

Answer (score 4):

The solution above not working for the latest version on PostgreSQL. I found this way to convert epoch time being stored in number and int column type is on PostgreSQL 13:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + (<table>.field::int) * INTERVAL '1 second' as started_on from <table>;
```

For more detail explanation, you can see here https://www.yodiw.com/convert-epoch-time-to-timestamp-in-postgresql/#more-214

Comment: The above solutions will most definitely work with Postgres 12 or 13. But you can simplify your solution to `make_timestamp(sec => the_column)`

Answer (score 3):

This works for me fine:

```
SELECT t.*,
   to_timestamp(cast(t.prev_fire_time/1000 as bigint)) as prev_fire_time,
   to_timestamp(cast(t.next_fire_time/1000 as bigint)) as next_fire_time,
   to_timestamp(cast(t.start_time/1000 as bigint)) as start_time
FROM public.qrtz_triggers t;
```

Answer (score 2):

Seconds since epoch with GNU `date`:

```
$ date +%s.%N
1627059870.945134901
```

This works with PostgreSQL 11:

```
# select to_timestamp (1627059870.945134901);
         to_timestamp          
-------------------------------
 2021-07-23 19:04:30.945135+02
(1 row)

# select to_timestamp (1627059870.945134901)::date;
 to_timestamp 
--------------
 2021-07-23
(1 row)
```