# Convert String epoch code from unix timestamp to date using sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, tableau-api, unix-timestamp, epoch

I need your help in converting this event_time to an ASCII SQL formated datatype.
A little background:
This data was retrieved from a Hadoop Hive data source using Tableau. Also, I was told it's a unix timestamp.
I have some extensive research done but seem to not be able to find any solution.

```
SELECT converted(event_time) from tablename; 

event_time
1610629690320
1610629939669
1610630516715
1610633038207
1610633886798
1610633991600
1610635895132
1610636069966
1610636135413
```

Comment: What does a `ASCII SQL formated datatype` look like?

Comment: Is that sample table data or the expected result? We need both anyway.

Comment: PostGres? duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609722/postgresql-how-to-convert-from-unix-epoch-to-date

Comment: What is `converted()`?

Comment: This site can help validate unix dates: https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: `select to_timestamp(1610629690320/1000); 2021-01-14 05:08:10-08`  The time is in milliseconds so you need to divide by thousands to get to Unix epoch seconds. Then you can use `to_timestamp()`.

Comment: I think tableau-api tag isn't appropriate here!

Answer (score 0):

**How to convert unix-timestamp to datetime in Tableau**

Create a calculated field:
DATEADD('second', INT([event_time]/1000),#1970-01-01#)

Reference:
https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/dates-display-unix-epoch-instead-of-date-datetime?_ga=2.128232396.1788694263.1612488670-1032121342.1608670166