# Postgres Citus, immutable date conversion

Tags: postgresql, immutability, citus

Trying to update some dates programmatically on Citus I always get

`[0A000] ERROR: STABLE functions used in UPDATE queries cannot be called with column references`

From a query like

```
UPDATE date_container SET json_value = json_value::jsonb - 'created_time' || CONCAT('{"created_time":"',
                                     rtrim(replace(to_timestamp(((json_value->>'created_time')::numeric/1000000))::text,' ','T'), '-05'),'"}')::jsonb
```

In theory all methods are `immutable`, but for some reasons it says that some part of it is not.

I tried also all methods below:
[PostgreSQL: how to convert from Unix epoch to date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609722/postgresql-how-to-convert-from-unix-epoch-to-date)

Comment: The problem is the implicit cast from `timestamp with time zone` to `text` that happens because you use it as an argument to `replace`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, any idea for the solution? I tried so many possible combinations

Comment: I tried to understand the query, but it makes no sense to me at all. What is that `-` supposed to do?, WHat is that attempt to concatenate the string `created_time` with a `jsonb`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe the goal is updating the jsonb `created_time` field. To do so, from my understanding I have to remove it and insert it again through that code.

Answer (score 1):

The `CONCAT` function is `stable` instead of `immutable`, this is often the case for functions that take `any`/`anyelement` as an argument.

```
select proname, pronamespace::regnamespace, provolatile
from pg_proc
where proname = 'concat';
 proname │ pronamespace │ provolatile
─────────┼──────────────┼─────────────
 concat  │ pg_catalog   │ s
```

Instead you should be able to use the string concatenation operator `||`, but be sure to cast all items to text, otherwise you might get the same problem with it using a anyelement version of the `||` operator.

So I think this query should work:

```
UPDATE date_container SET json_value = json_value::jsonb - 'created_time' ||
   (
      '{"created_time":"'::text
      || rtrim(replace(to_timestamp(((json_value->>'created_time')::numeric/1000000))::text,' ','T'), '-05')::text
      || '"}'::text
   )::jsonb
```