# timestamp string to timestamp in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, stripe-payments

Date data saved from stripe start_date as string timestamp like "1652789095".
Now I want to filter with this timestamp string form last 12 months.
what should I do ?
how can I filter with this timestamp string?

Comment: this looks like a unix timestamp. Some answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609722/postgresql-how-to-convert-from-unix-epoch-to-date and here: https://www.postgresonline.com/article_pfriendly/3.html

Comment: I would imagine as well that you can subtract 31536000 (the number of seconds in a year) from 1652789095 and that is the number you are looking for as well ( records where start_date is greater than 1621253095) :)

Comment: Actually date saved in database as string timestamp. Now my goal is filter with this timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

These are some examples - I'm sure there are plenty of options that would work.

#### convert to date

```
select *
from Table
where 
  to_timestamp(cast(start_date as int)::date > date_add(now(), interval -1 year);
```

#### work with unix timestamps

```
-- approx 1 year ago, by way of example
select * 
from Table
where
  start_date > '1621253095';

-- exactly one year ago, calculated dynamically
select * 
from Table 
where 
  start_date > 
    cast(unix_timestamp(date_add(now(), interval -1 year)) as varchar);
```

I'm not a MySQL guy really so forgive any syntax errors and fix up the sql as needed to work in MySQL.

Resources:

[PostgreSQL: how to convert from Unix epoch to date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609722/postgresql-how-to-convert-from-unix-epoch-to-date)

https://www.postgresonline.com/article_pfriendly/3.html