# Is there anyway to extract only date from epoch time stamp in sql alchemy

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy

Function to convert given epoch timestamp to date.

```
def extract_date_from_epoch(epoch: int) -> str:
    return datetime.utcfromtimestamp(epoch).date()
```

I have an analytic table with the below columns in there.

```
class Analytic(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'analytic'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    record_timestamp = Column(Integer)
    consumed_time = Column(Integer)
    profile_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('profile.id'))
    conversation_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('conversation.id'))
```

I want to get the total consumed time and filter by profile id and date I gave to it. also, results should be grouped by conversation_id.

Here is my current query without the date filter.

`analytic_get_stmt = select(Analytic.conversation_id,func.sum(Analytic.consumed_time).label("total_time")).where(Analytic.profile_id == profile_id).group_by(Analytic.conversation_id)`

**So is there any method I can filter the data by date?** If not I think the best method is to get all the data and filter it using Python without the SQL like below.

```
analytic_get_stmt = select(Analytic.conversation_id, Analytic.record_timestamp, Analytic.consumed_time). \
            where(Analytic.profile_id == profile_id)
        analytic_data = self.session.execute(analytic_get_stmt)

        conversation_ids = []
        total_consumed_time = 0

        for data in analytic_data:
            if extract_date_from_epoch(data.record_timestamp) == date:
                if data.conversation_id not in conversation_ids:
                    conversation_ids.append(data.conversation_id)
                total_consumed_time += data.consumed_time
```

Comment: I'm using the Postgres database locally.

Answer (score 0):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16609722/5320906), you can convert an epoch timestamp to a date like this:

```sql
select to_timestamp(record_timestamp)::date from analytic;
```

The equivalent SQLAlchemy expression would be

```py
sa.select(sa.cast(sa.func.to_timestamp(Analytic.record_timestamp), sa.Date))
```

Thus your `GROUP BY` query would be

```py
analytic_get_stmt = (
    sa.select(
        Analytic.conversation_id,
        sa.func.sum(Analytic.consumed_time).label('total_time'),
    )
    .where(
        sa.and_(
            Analytic.profile_id == profile_id,
            sa.cast(sa.func.to_timestamp(Analytic.record_timestamp), sa.Date)
            == date,
        )
    )
    .group_by(Analytic.conversation_id)
)
```

Using the expression in a `WHERE` clause will not be very performant, so it would be good to add a functional index that pre-computed the date values. Unfortunately, PostgreSQL does not seem to allow this, perhaps because the timezone of the timestamp is no known with certainty.